# Where is "msvcR140.dll"? Does it exist?

Tags: visual-studio-2015, wix, vcredist

I have recently graduated to VS 2015. For reasons explained below, I want to avoid running the VC++ Redistributables installer. I am including the prescribed DLLs in my installer, for an "app local" installation:

```
MFC140.DLL
concrt140.dll
msvcp140.dll
vccorlib140.dll
vcruntime140.dll
mfc140u.dll
mfcm140u.dll
```

This seems to work. My app runs when installed thus on a "virgin" PC.

> My question is, where do I find `msvcr140.dll`?

It is mentioned here: https://www.visualstudio.com/license-terms/mt228262/. I cannot find it anywhere when searching all directories on a PC where VC Redistributables has been installed. Does it exist? Is Windows concealing it?

---

**Note 1**: Why I need to avoid the MS VC++ Redistributables installer:

- It shows up as a separate install in my WiX installer. It is very confusing for my market demographic (consumers).
- When my software is uninstalled, it is also necessary to uninstall VC Redist., which can lead to complications.
- In a couple of instances, there has been some sort of screw-up that has rendered the PC inoperable. I suspect repeated VC Redist installs. What happens is that a Standard User is no longer able to start any programs.
- VC Redist. has bloated my installer from 25MB to 40MB, an extra 15MB. By picking which components I need, I trimmed it by 10 MB.
- WiX code to test for prior versions is complex, arcane and inscrutable.
- Yes, I understand about the benefits of automatic updating of Windows DLLs. However, a PC with out-of-date DLLs is better than a PC that is unusable.

---

**Note 2**: I can't do a static link, my app is a mixed bag of Win32 and MFC DLLs, I get linker errors.

Comment: Another option is to install the c++ runtime files via a mergemodule (from Program Files [(x86)]\Common Files\Merge Modules): https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms235299.aspx

Comment: Morten Frederiksen Thanks for the reply. What are Merge Modules? How do I use them with WiX? Wouldn't I be running the same risk of corrupting the system?

Comment: Here's a guide on how to include a mergemodule in your WiX code: http://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/howtos/redistributables_and_install_checks/install_vcredist.html

Comment: Merge module won't gain you anything over the separate VC redist installer. It's still more bloat than including only needed DLLs and it updates system DLLs.

Comment: Thanks for the link Morten Frederiksen. zett42: That's a deal breaker  :o)

Answer (score 3):

It appears that the "msvcr140.dll" is "missing" because of the [introduction of the Universal CRT](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/vcblog/2015/03/03/introducing-the-universal-crt/) in Visual Studio 2015.

See also [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35806815/7571258) and [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32602828/7571258).

Looking inside the official merge module located at `Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Merge Modules\Microsoft_VC140_CRT_x64.msm`, the Visual C++ 2015 CRT consists of these files:

```
api-ms-win-core-console-l1-1-0.dll
api-ms-win-core-datetime-l1-1-0.dll
api-ms-win-core-debug-l1-1-0.dll
api-ms-win-core-errorhandling-l1-1-0.dll
api-ms-win-core-file-l1-1-0.dll
api-ms-win-core-file-l1-2-0.dll
api-ms-win-core-file-l2-1-0.dll
api-ms-win-core-handle-l1-1-0.dll
api-ms-win-core-heap-l1-1-0.dll
api-ms-win-core-interlocked-l1-1-0.dll
api-ms-win-core-libraryloader-l1-1-0.dll
api-ms-win-core-localization-l1-2-0.dll
api-ms-win-core-memory-l1-1-0.dll
api-ms-win-core-namedpipe-l1-1-0.dll
api-ms-win-core-processenvironment-l1-1-0.dll
api-ms-win-core-processthreads-l1-1-0.dll
api-ms-win-core-processthreads-l1-1-1.dll
api-ms-win-core-profile-l1-1-0.dll
api-ms-win-core-rtlsupport-l1-1-0.dll
api-ms-win-core-string-l1-1-0.dll
api-ms-win-core-synch-l1-1-0.dll
api-ms-win-core-synch-l1-2-0.dll
api-ms-win-core-sysinfo-l1-1-0.dll
api-ms-win-core-timezone-l1-1-0.dll
api-ms-win-core-util-l1-1-0.dll
api-ms-win-crt-conio-l1-1-0.dll
api-ms-win-crt-convert-l1-1-0.dll
api-ms-win-crt-environment-l1-1-0.dll
api-ms-win-crt-filesystem-l1-1-0.dll
api-ms-win-crt-heap-l1-1-0.dll
api-ms-win-crt-locale-l1-1-0.dll
api-ms-win-crt-math-l1-1-0.dll
api-ms-win-crt-multibyte-l1-1-0.dll
api-ms-win-crt-private-l1-1-0.dll
api-ms-win-crt-process-l1-1-0.dll
api-ms-win-crt-runtime-l1-1-0.dll
api-ms-win-crt-stdio-l1-1-0.dll
api-ms-win-crt-string-l1-1-0.dll
api-ms-win-crt-time-l1-1-0.dll
api-ms-win-crt-utility-l1-1-0.dll
concrt140.dll
msvcp140.dll
ucrtbase.dll
vccorlib140.dll
vcruntime140.dll
```

Comment: Honest zett42 this is all I see in "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\redist\x86\Microsoft.VC140.CRT": concrt140.dll
msvcp140.dll
vccorlib140.dll
vcruntime140.dll. There is no "msvcR140.dll". There used to be in VS2010, but alas no more.

Comment: @Pierre I should have actually looked into this folder. But I found the explanation why this DLL appears to be missing, see updated answer.

Comment: I found them in "C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Redist\ucrt\DLLs\x86\". I see that Firefox and Tortoise/SVN include the whole api-ms-win-*.dll set in their installation directory. Well, if it's good enough for them ...