# Cython: Missing MSVCR140.dll

Tags: python, python-3.x, cython, msvcrt, visual-c++-2015

I want to test out Cython with Python. When I run `python setup.py build_ext --compiler=mingw32` (I use GCC from MSYS2 on Windows) it tells me `cannot find -lmsvcr140` (MSVCR140.dll). From [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43873604/where-is-msvcr140-dll-does-it-exist), it seems that this file missing since Visual C++2015 Redistributables introduced and replaced by VCRuntime140.dll. My question is how do I tell Cython to use VCRuntime.dll instead?

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I update MinGW into MinGW-w64 (prooved to be critical),
and edit the code snippet in `cygwinccompiler.py`:

```
    elif int(msc_ver) >= 1900:
        # VS2015 / MSVC 14.0
        # return ['msvcr140']
        return ['vcruntime140']
```

then put `vcruntime140.dll` into `/path/to/mingw-w64/lib`, then solve the problem.