# WiX Toolset installs VC++ redistributable (x86) 2015 too slowly

Tags: wix, windows-installer, vcredist

I wrote a WiX Toolset Setup to install an application which requires the VC++ redistributable (x86) 2015. Everything works fine, but when vcredlist_x86.exe  is launched,  it installs the Package too slowly, it takers about six minutes !

If I run the vcredlist in standalone mode, it still takes six minutes, as timeline shows:

```
[1190:1364][2017-05-29T10:56:06]i001: Burn v3.7.2829.0, Windows v6.1 (Build 7601: Service Pack 1), path: D:\TestApplication\MyInstaller\vcredlist\vcredist_x86.exe, cmdline: '/install /log install.log -burn.unelevated BurnPipe.{5745A989-148E-49D2-9BAA-882CBAF76EC9} {C40DCBEA-3CC3-401E-88A3-E0685CD9D368} 4692'
[1190:1364][2017-05-29T10:56:06]i000: Setting string variable 'WixBundleLog' to value 'D:\TestApplication\MyInstaller\vcredlist\install.log'
[1190:1364][2017-05-29T10:56:06]i000: Setting string variable 'WixBundleOriginalSource' to value 'D:\TestApplication\MyInstaller\vcredlist\vcredist_x86.exe'
[1190:1364][2017-05-29T10:56:06]i000: Setting string variable 'WixBundleName' to value 'Microsoft Visual C++ 2015 Redistributable (x86) - 12.0.30501'
[1190:1364][2017-05-29T10:56:06]i100: Detect begin, 2 packages
[1190:1364][2017-05-29T10:56:06]i101: Detected package: vcRuntimeMinimum_x86, state: Present, cached: Complete
[1190:1364][2017-05-29T10:56:06]i101: Detected package: vcRuntimeAdditional_x86, state: Present, cached: Complete
[1190:1364][2017-05-29T10:56:06]i052: Condition 'VersionNT >= v6.0 OR (VersionNT = v5.1 AND ServicePackLevel >= 2) OR (VersionNT = v5.2 AND ServicePackLevel >= 1)' evaluates to true.
[1190:1364][2017-05-29T10:56:06]i199: Detect complete, result: 0x0
[1190:1364][2017-05-29T10:56:46]i200: Plan begin, 2 packages, action: Install
[1190:1364][2017-05-29T10:56:46]i201: Planned package: vcRuntimeMinimum_x86, state: Present, default requested: Present, ba requested: Present, execute: None, rollback: None, cache: No, uncache: No, dependency: Register
[1190:1364][2017-05-29T10:56:46]i201: Planned package: vcRuntimeAdditional_x86, state: Present, default requested: Present, ba requested: Present, execute: None, rollback: None, cache: No, uncache: No, dependency: Register
[1190:1364][2017-05-29T10:56:46]i299: Plan complete, result: 0x0
[1190:1364][2017-05-29T10:56:46]i300: Apply begin
[1254:1CC0][2017-05-29T11:02:52]w308: Automatic updates could not be paused due to error: 0x80080005. Continuing...
[1254:1CC0][2017-05-29T11:02:52]i360: Creating a system restore point.
[1254:1CC0][2017-05-29T11:02:57]i361: Created a system restore point.
[1254:1CC0][2017-05-29T11:02:57]i370: Session begin, registration key: SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\{f65db027-aff3-4070-886a-0d87064aabb1}, options: 0x7, disable resume: No
[1254:1CC0][2017-05-29T11:02:57]i000: Caching bundle from: 'C:\Users\costanzo\AppData\Local\Temp\{f65db027-aff3-4070-886a-0d87064aabb1}\.be\vcredist_x86.exe' to: 'C:\ProgramData\Package Cache\{f65db027-aff3-4070-886a-0d87064aabb1}\vcredist_x86.exe'
[1254:1CC0][2017-05-29T11:02:57]i320: Registering bundle dependency provider: {f65db027-aff3-4070-886a-0d87064aabb1}, version: 12.0.30501.0
[1254:1CC0][2017-05-29T11:02:57]i371: Updating session, registration key: SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\{f65db027-aff3-4070-886a-0d87064aabb1}, resume: Active, restart initiated: No, disable resume: No
[1254:1CC0][2017-05-29T11:02:57]i325: Registering dependency: {f65db027-aff3-4070-886a-0d87064aabb1} on package provider: Microsoft.VS.VC_RuntimeMinimumVSU_x86,v12, package: vcRuntimeMinimum_x86
[1254:1CC0][2017-05-29T11:02:57]i325: Registering dependency: {f65db027-aff3-4070-886a-0d87064aabb1} on package provider: Microsoft.VS.VC_RuntimeAdditionalVSU_x86,v12, package: vcRuntimeAdditional_x86
[1254:1CC0][2017-05-29T11:02:57]i372: Session end, registration key: SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\{f65db027-aff3-4070-886a-0d87064aabb1}, resume: ARP, restart: None, disable resume: No
[1254:1CC0][2017-05-29T11:02:57]i371: Updating session, registration key: SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\{f65db027-aff3-4070-886a-0d87064aabb1}, resume: ARP, restart initiated: No, disable resume: No
[1190:1364][2017-05-29T11:02:57]i399: Apply complete, result: 0x0, restart: None, ba requested restart:  No
[1190:1364][2017-05-29T11:07:50]i500: Shutting down, exit code: 0x0
[1190:1364][2017-05-29T11:07:50]i410: Variable: ServicePackLevel = 1
[1190:1364][2017-05-29T11:07:50]i410: Variable: VersionNT = 6.1.0.0
[1190:1364][2017-05-29T11:07:50]i410: Variable: WixBundleAction = 5
[1190:1364][2017-05-29T11:07:50]i410: Variable: WixBundleElevated = 1
[1190:1364][2017-05-29T11:07:50]i410: Variable: WixBundleInstalled = 0
[1190:1364][2017-05-29T11:07:50]i410: Variable: WixBundleLog = D:\TestApplication\MyInstaller\vcredlist\install.log
[1190:1364][2017-05-29T11:07:50]i410: Variable: WixBundleManufacturer = Microsoft Corporation
[1190:1364][2017-05-29T11:07:50]i410: Variable: WixBundleName = Microsoft Visual C++ 2015 Redistributable (x86) - 12.0.30501
[1190:1364][2017-05-29T11:07:50]i410: Variable: WixBundleOriginalSource = D:\TestApplication\MyInstaller\vcredlist\vcredist_x86.exe
[1190:1364][2017-05-29T11:07:50]i410: Variable: WixBundleProviderKey = {f65db027-aff3-4070-886a-0d87064aabb1}
[1190:1364][2017-05-29T11:07:50]i410: Variable: WixBundleTag = 
[1190:1364][2017-05-29T11:07:50]i410: Variable: WixBundleVersion = 12.0.30501.0
[1190:1364][2017-05-29T11:07:50]i007: Exit code: 0x0, restarting: No
```

What could be the reason, and how this problem could be solved?

Comment: Which operating system are you running the installer on?

Comment: Windows 7 Professional

Comment: To get some insight into why the VC Redist is taking so long you could try running it in standalone mode with logging enabled.  Use a command line like: `vc_Redist.x86.exe /install /log install.log`.

Comment: Fastest way: get rid of vcredist installer altogether and use [app-local deployment of the runtime](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32601941/7571258).

Comment: The Post is not useful at all, unfortunately !

@bradfordrg, the log says practically nothing. Any other ideas?

Comment: Can you add the log to the question?  Then we can all see what the log says.  Does running the VC++ redistributable in standalone mode still take six minutes?

Comment: Yes,  the same time. I edited my question with log, as you suggested me

Answer (score 2):

The reason for VC++ redistributable taking 6 minutes is probably caused by issues with **Windows Update** on the computer you are running the installer on.

The VC++ redistributable uses the WIX burn engine (part of the [WIX Toolset](http://wixtoolset.org/)).  During the installation process the WIX Burn engine will try to pause automatic updates.  This line in the log file indicates pausing automatic updates has failed after taking approximately 6 minutes to timeout:

```
[1254:1CC0][2017-05-29T11:02:52]w308: Automatic updates could not be paused due to error: 0x80080005. Continuing...
```

Error code 0x8008005 is Windows COM error CO_E_SERVER_EXEC_FAILURE, which translates to "Server execution failed".  An explanation of why this error can occur can be found in the article [When CoCreateInstance returns 0x80080005 (CO_E_SERVER_EXEC_FAILURE)](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/adioltean/2005/06/24/when-cocreateinstance-returns-0x80080005-co_e_server_exec_failure/).

Suggest looking more closely at **Windows Update** on the target computer to see what is going on.

Comment: Yes, looking in the WiX source code it does look like this is the case - Windows Update is probably broken (malware?), or stuck somehow. [**It seems it is the call to Microsoft.Update.AutoUpdate which hangs**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49534494/129130). I guess a better error message might suffice. Or taking out the whole call?

Comment: Better error feedback would be a help. Before taking out the call I would like to better understand the reasons for the call being there.

Comment: I agree - in my opinion a very likely cause of the hang could be malware having broken Windows Update (I have seen it many times). Would it be very strange for WiX / Burn to suggest this as a possibility to the user? Maybe it would be unnecessarily alarmist? My 2 cents: with malware on the box no reliable deployment can be expected. I'd expect to see further errors, and the user might not connect the dots immediately?