# WiX behaving badly on XP machine with windows update issues

Tags: wix, windows-update

My WiX bundle behaves very badly on a specific XP machine (x86). It stalls for six minutes during the "initializing" phase (before any bundled installers are run). From the logs it seems extremely likely it is due to the dodgy state of windows update on the machine:

```
[090C:0FC0][2018-03-27T19:31:17]i358: Pausing automatic updates.
[090C:0FC0][2018-03-27T19:37:23]w308: Automatic updates could not be paused due to error: 0x80080005. Continuing...
[090C:0FC0][2018-03-27T19:37:23]i360: Creating a system restore point.
```

I am using WiX v3.10 to make the bundle. I can find very similar situations from google search but the solution always revolves around updating the target machine. I need this installer to work as expected regardless. When I test a regular msi on the same machine it goes through fine.

Is there any way I can mitigate this issue? E.g. can I stop the WiX bundle from trying to pause windows update or something similar? The fact that the installer doesn't even notify what the issue is is extremely problematic, any user is likely to be confused.

The whole point of this WiX installer is to make an install package portable and simple but this actually seems LESS portable than just the msi...

Update: Also tried building the bundle with WiX 3.11 but got same problem. Though now it produces an actual error rather than installing regardless, which I suppose is an improvement.

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44197835/wix-toolset-installs-vc-redistributable-x86-2015-too-slowly

Comment: It looks like I had built the bundle badly. I rebuilt everything with WiX 3.10 and it no longer rushed through the installation after the timeout. It still pauses for 6 minutes due to the windows update issue, but this is acceptable as it doesn't jeopardize the installation (unlike what it was doing previously). I have updated the question to reflect this.

Comment: XP? Yikes.  I would be sure to tell the customer support is best effort and only basically tested on a fully patched XP with functioning windows update.

Comment: I am almost convinced this is malware - sorry to say. Hope not though. Please see my updated answer below. I think I found the hanging COM call, but I guess that doesn't really help much.

Answer (score 2):

**UPDATE**: after looking in the WiX source code it looks like WiX's Burn feature is making a few calls to `Microsoft.Update.AutoUpdate` (`%SystemRoot%\System32\usoapi.dll` - `%SystemRoot%\SysWOW64\wuapi.dll`) and a few other COM objects here and there.

*See towards the bottom (screenshot) for a **hot COM tip** to quickly get an overview of different COM object models*.

It must be this AutoUpdate call which hangs causing a timout along the lines of what is described in [this blog](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/adioltean/2005/06/24/when-cocreateinstance-returns-0x80080005-co_e_server_exec_failure/). I believe you can find the exact source code location by searching for `hr = WuaPauseAutomaticUpdates();` in [the elevation.cpp WiX Burn source file](https://github.com/wixtoolset/wix3/blob/wix3111/src/burn/engine/elevation.cpp) (Github link). The actual calls to the COM object are in [wuautil.cpp](https://github.com/wixtoolset/wix3/blob/wix3111/src/libs/dutil/wuautil.cpp).

I am not familiar with [the Windows Update Agent Object Model](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa387291%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), but I suppose you could try to call the `Pause` function in a test VBScript just to see what kind of error you get on your problem system (if any). I can't see how you would get anything but a lockup on your problem system, so maybe try first on your main box? **This is obviously at your own risk**. I would assume a reboot or a call to `Resume` will continue the process as normal. I also see a call to `SystemInformation.RebootRequired` in the C++ code, which I have also added to the VBScript:

```vb
Set autoupdate = CreateObject("Microsoft.Update.AutoUpdate")
autoupdate.Pause()
MsgBox Err.Number & " " & Err.Description

Set sys = CreateObject("Microsoft.Update.SystemInfo")
MsgBox sys.RebootRequired

' autoupdate.Resume() ' Enable to resume AutoUpdate
Set sys = Nothing
Set autoupdate = Nothing
```

***Let's face it: Windows Update is broken on your XP machine - isn't it? Maybe the WiX guys can add a shorter timeout?*** I am not sure what is better - `1)` to shorten the timeout, `2)` to remove the whole call or `3)` to just bomb out telling the user that Windows Update is broken? Frankly the latter would probably alert the user to something very serious (often malware).

**UPDATE**: as you state yourself, Windows Update is almost certainly broken on this particular machine. I would try the MSI properties suggested below for testing, and then [zap Windows Update as suggested here](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/all/windows-update-error-0x80080005-2013-19-t-065144a/f88b7a31-7698-4192-8035-212797cc89ae?auth=1) (same link as below) ([techical](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/adioltean/2005/06/24/when-cocreateinstance-returns-0x80080005-co_e_server_exec_failure/)).

But wait, maybe a **malware check** is in order, before wasting time on anything else?

- [**Maybe try this free Sysinternals tool**](https://twitter.com/glytzhkof/status/943103096569454592)? Checks all running processes by hash using almost 70 scanning engines (no heuristics though). Fire up all you got (only running processes are checked)
- Go `File` => `Show Details for All Processes` and then elevate to get to scan system processes as well. Now click "System" to scan drivers for example (*.sys files).
- Often a great way to get your system admin to agree to rebuild a problematic machine for everyone. Suddenly you go from "deployment problem" to "machine specific problem" - and it is out of your hair. GIGO problem.

Nicely formatted and phrased question BTW. And just for reference: [Sysinternals](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/).

---

### Workaround?

I have never seen this, but I have seen some MSI files suddenly pausing for a long time whilst installing whereas they would install quickly during test installs just minutes before.

My guess is that this could be related to **system restore** and **the creation of a restore point** at certain "intervals". I am not sure what algorithm is used to determine when such a restore point is created and not, but I wrote an answer many years ago on the issue of speeding up MSI installations: [**How can I speed up MSI package install and uninstall?**](https://serverfault.com/questions/594660/how-can-i-speed-up-msi-package-install-and-uninstall/594661#594661)

As you will see, you can disable the creation of a restore point for your setup by setting an appropriate command line involving the property [**MSIFASTINSTALL**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd408005%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) (and a few other tweaks - please just read the linked serverfault.com answer). I would try this to see if your setup stops locking up / hanging.

---

### Causes?

Some hits from the web:

- Could it be that Windows Updates is also trying to create a restore point at the same time as your MSI-package? [Setup hang when trying to disable windows updates](http://windows-installer-xml-wix-toolset.687559.n2.nabble.com/Setup-hang-when-trying-to-disable-windows-updates-td7593734.html) (PhilDW)
- [Could it be that the Windows Update feature is corrupted?](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/all/windows-update-error-0x80080005-2013-19-t-065144a/f88b7a31-7698-4192-8035-212797cc89ae?auth=1)
- Similar issue: [WiX Toolset installs VC++ redistributable (x86) 2015 too slowly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44197835/wx-toolset-installs-vc-redistributable-x86-2015-too-slowly)

I would first try the **MSI properties** mentioned as a "workaround" above, and if that doesn't work, I would try to see if **fixing Windows Update** as explained in the link directly above works. Crucially I would also let Windows Update complete its task of installing all available updates before running your bundle again.

---

### Hot Tip (COM)

**I don't like to recommend commercial tools**, but we all need some **quick tricks** and **quick wins** at times - which is what this is about. Get hold of [**VbsEdit**](http://www.vbsedit.com/) and use its **light weight object browser** to quickly see details from any COM object model. Just do a `CreateObject` and you will instantly see the object model in the object browser to the right in the application window (`View => Object Browser` if it is not there).

Just type in something like this:

```vb
Set installer = CreateObject("WindowsInstaller.Installer")
```

[image: VbsEdit COM Object Browser]

I find this to be a time-saver when I need to deal with legacy COM stuff and Visual Studio is very sluggish. I just have the VbsEdit trial version, and it allows basic editing. And let's throw in a rant: why on earth do they not make a Javascript version? I am missing something - as usual :-).

Throwing in a second screen shot to show a more interesting object model information tidbit:

[image: Object model information]

Should you want to try it, here are some other CreateObject statements you can try:

```vb
Set autoupdate = CreateObject("Microsoft.Update.AutoUpdate")
Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set scriptshell = CreateObject ("WScript.Shell")
Set dictionary = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
Set shell = CreateObject("Shell.Application")
```

Comment: Thanks for the thorough answer. Except on this machine a regular msi works fine (as stated in the question), so I would assume this is a WiX related issue. The chief purpose of this installer is to be portable and reliable, so I would like this to work on this machine even if there are problems on it (the problems can't be THAT bad since a regular msi works). So I unfortunately can't use "your machine is broken" as a solution (I'd rather avoid it anyway). Also, with MSIFASTINSTALL, this is an XP machine, which isn't guaranteed to have Windows Installer 4.5 (is it?)

Comment: OK, I had a look in the WiX source code. Please see the updated answer above. The **VBScript** should be fine, it is just pausing the update component, but **as always use at your own risk**. Good luck, hope you find a solution. Is this a very important machine? Fingers crossed you don't find malware. Please check though - gut feel is there is something there. Just my 2 cents...

Comment: Yes, sorry. Blond moment there with XP and Windows Installer version. In my mind only Windows 7,8 and 10 exist these days :-).

Comment: @SteinÅsmul - Hi Stein. I've seen 2 of your answers, including this. I must say that you're one of the best writer. This is one of the very few detailed answer including the VS related answer (around 10 days back) where you almost utilised SO's entire space to describe the problem in detail. I appreciate your knowledge & skills; hope I'd write answers someday like you.

Comment: @Am_I_Helpful - Thank you very much for kind words. Sometimes I feel I answer everything but the actual question that was asked :-) - happens more often than I would like. The links and the comments quickly become too many as you debug and test, but I think we should leave in our debugging progress for others to see in case they get better ideas looking at the steps we have gone through.